How do I navigate to a different page in my app using React Material UI Select?
I want to navigate to a new page depending on what is selected in a Material UI Select component.  Here is the
SelectFoodChange.js :
import * as React from 'react';
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function SelectFoodChange() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    navigate(`./${value}`) 
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 120 }}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-helper-label">Food Page</InputLabel>
        <Select
          label="Food Page"
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <MenuItem value="BrandedFoods">Branded Foods</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="WholeFoods">Whole Foods</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}

Here is Food page which imports SelectFoodPage component:
Food.js
import React from 'react';
import SelectFoodPage from './SelectFoodPage';
function Food() {
  return (
    <div className='Food'>
       {<SelectFoodPage />}
     </div>
  );
}
export default Food;

Here is how I change pages depending on selected item in a burger menu:
App.js
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Food from './pages/food/Food';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Home />}></Route>
          <Route path='/food' element={<Food />}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </>
  )
}

export default App;

Here is BrandedFood.js.  It is located in the same folder as Food.js.
BrandedFood.js
import React from 'react';

function BrandedFoods() {
  return (
    <div className='branded-foods'>
      <h1>BRANDED FOODS PAGE</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
export default BrandedFoods;

I want the Select component to remain visible regardless of which page it navigates to.  Currently, when I select "Branded Food", the url at the top of the pages shows
http://localhost:3000/food/BrandedFoods

but it doesn't seem to do anything.  It doesn't navigate to BrandedFoods.js.
How do I navigate to a new page depending on what is selected in a Material UI Select component?

You can use the useNavigate hook from react-router-dom in the handleChange function.
import * as React from 'react';
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function SelectFoodChange() {
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState('');
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    if (value === 'something'){
        navigate(`/${value}`) 
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 120 }}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-helper-label">Food Page</InputLabel>
        <Select
          value={page}
          label="Food Page"
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <MenuItem value="branded-foods">Branded Foods</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="whole-foods">Whole Foods</MenuItem>

        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}


I updated the post to show your suggestions, however it didn't seem to do anything.  What am I missing?

You are missing const navigate = useNavigate();

I had it in my code but forgot to add it to the edited post.  I updated that now.

I got it working by modifying App.js: "import BrandedFood from './pages/food/BrandedFoods';" and adding another Route "<Route path='/food/BrandedFoods' element={}>.  I don't understand why I had to do that.  It seems redundant.  Regardless, now the Select dropdown is gone so I'll need to figure out how to fix that too.  Thanks for your suggestion!  I'll mark it as the answer.

Every route needs to be defined else in cases of a dynamic route. That is why you had to define the route. If you had set up a dynamic route '/food/:type', then all route matching /food/[something] will be rendered for the page.
I also spotted a in the navigate function call, you have ./${value} instead of /${value}

Actually, I got it working using navigate(../food/${value});  If I just used / then the url became localhost:3000/BrandedFoods.  But by your comment I realized that I confused the path in the .  I was putting the full path in there, rather than just a variable.  I fixed that so now the url shows localhost:3000/branded-foods, rather than localhost:3000/food/BrandedFoods, and only need the /${value} like you said.  I also got the  dropdown to stay on every page by using .
